# Additively applying EdgeStyle to a graph without resetting

Tags: graphs-and-networks, style

```
w = {3, 4, 10, 2, 1}; 
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4}, EdgeWeight -> w]; 
p = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 4};
```

Then I set their EdgeStyle to reflect the Edgeweights:

```
Table[PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeWeight], {e, EdgeList[g]}]; 
{min, max} = {Min[#], Max[#]} &@% 
Do[PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeStyle] = AbsoluteThickness[Rescale[PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeWeight], {min, max}, {1, 7}]], {e, EdgeList[g]}]
```

However, I also want to color certain edges a color... so I attempt to use:

```
Do[PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeStyle] = {Green}, {e,p}]
```

The result is that the edges get colored green, except they are green without displaying the thickness I assigned to them earlier. I know why it's happening... I'm resetting `EdgeStyle` for those edges.

My attempt to circumvent this: I figured that we use Epilog here?-right? It gives me the same result when I use:

```
HighlightGraph[g, p, Epilog -> Green]
```

This gives me the same output as `Do[PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeStyle] = {Green}, {e,p}]`

How can I apply a color to certain edges once I've assigned their thicknesses?

Comment: `Do[PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeStyle] = Directive[Green, PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeStyle]], {e, p}]`?

Comment: or `HighlightGraph[g, 
 Style[#, PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeStyle], Green] & /@ p]`?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comment, what we can do is simply alter `Do[PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeStyle]` slightly to include the additional styling for subgraph `p`:

```
Table[PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeWeight], {e, EdgeList[g]}]; {min, max} = {Min[#], Max[#]} &@% 
Do[PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeStyle] = AbsoluteThickness[Rescale[PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeWeight], {min, max}, {1, 7}]], {e, EdgeList[g]}]
Do[PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeStyle] = Directive[Green, PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeStyle]], {e, p}]
```

Alternatively, this can be applied with `HighlightGraph` as explain in the comments as well: `HighlightGraph[g, Style[#, PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeStyle], Green] & /@ p]`